# Knockout binding not triggered when resetting form

Tags: knockout.js

I have a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889491/input-type-reset-and-knockout) and I can't find a solution. I have this binding in a view

```
<div class="validation-summary-errors">
    <span data-bind="visible: $root.addErrors().length > 0">Please correct the following errors:</span>
    <!-- ko foreach: $root.addErrors -->
    <ul data-bind="text: error"></ul>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

And in the js I have these two methods and observableArray

```
this.addErrors = ko.observableArray();

this.deactiveAddForm = function () {
    self.addFormIsActive(false);
    self.hasReminder(false);
    self.addErrors([]);
    utils.resetForm('addEventForm');
};

this.add = function () {
    var form = document.getElementById('addEventForm');
    if ($(form).valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: form.action,
            type: form.method,
            data: $(form).serialize()
        }).done(function (result) {
            if (result.valError) {
                self.addErrors(ko.utils.arrayMap(result.addErrors, function (addError) {
                    return { error: addError };
                }));
            } else {
                self.deactiveAddForm();
                submissionSuccess(result.groups);
            }
        }).fail(function (jqXHr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            self.addErrors([{ error: errorThrown }]);
        });
    }
    return false;
};
```

The problem is that calling utils.resetForm('addEventForm') prevents the binding to work so the errors are not displayed in the view (although are present in the observable array).

Here is this method

```
resetForm: function (id) {
    var addForm = $(document.getElementById(id));

    if (addForm.length > 0) {
        addForm[0].reset();

        // Clear the inputs
        addForm.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
        addForm.find('input:radio, input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
        $(".selectMenu").trigger("liszt:updated");
    }
},
```

I couldn't trigger it with self.addErrors.valueHasMutated()

Is there a way of forcing the visible binding to work?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that...  Are you sure that this.addErrors and self.addErrors are refering to the same object in the same context?  Where are you defining self in your code?

Comment: Yes, they are in the viewmodel I define var self = this at the beginning of it.

Comment: Instead of `this.addErrors` do `self.addErrors` and declare self as the first statement in your viewmodel and the same for `this.deactiveAddForm` and `this.add`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code is your issue, I am not a knockout pro but haven't done this before

```
 self.addErrors(ko.utils.arrayMap(result.addErrors, function (addError) {
                return { error: addError };
            }));
```

Maybe rather do

```
self.addErrors.push({error: 'error'});
```

and see what happens

If this does not solve it can you create a jsfiddle with the issue?

**UPDATE**

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9kScC/)

So for your code:

```
var vm = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.addErrors = ko.observableArray();

    self.deactiveAddForm = function () {
        self.addFormIsActive(false);
        self.hasReminder(false);
        self.addErrors([]);
         utils.resetForm('addEventForm');
    };

    self.add = function () {
        if ($(form).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: form.action,
                type: form.method,
                data: $(form).serialize()
            }).done(function (result) {
                if (result.valError) {
                    self.addErrors.push({
                        error: result.addErrors
                    });


                } else {
                    self.deactiveAddForm();
                    submissionSuccess(result.groups);
                }
            }).fail(function (jqXHr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                self.addErrors.push({
                    error: errorThrown 
                });
            });
        }
        return false;


    };


};
```

Comment: I will try to create a jsfiddle. I have tried push insted of the utils.arrayMap but didn't work neither

Comment: Just read up on `arrayMap` pretty cool function, let us know about the fiddle and I will modify my answer

Comment: Yes, I created this fiddle and it seems to work so it must be something else in the code http://jsfiddle.net/QPPTf/

Comment: @mitomed have you solved your issue? If not are you getting any JavaScript errors

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the context properly.

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.addFormIsActive = ko.observable();
    self.hasReminder = ko.observable(true);
    self.addErrors = ko.observableArray();

    self.deactiveAddForm = function () {
        self.addFormIsActive(false);
        self.hasReminder(false);
        self.addErrors([]);
        utils.resetForm('addEventForm');
    };

    self.add = function () {
        var form = document.getElementById('addEventForm');
        if ($(form).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: form.action,
                type: form.method,
                data: $(form).serialize()
            }).done(function (result) {
                if (result.valError) {
                    self.addErrors(ko.utils.arrayMap(result.addErrors, function (addError) {
                        return { error: addError };
                    }));
                } else {
                    self.deactiveAddForm();
                    submissionSuccess(result.groups);
                }
            }).fail(function (jqXHr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                self.addErrors([{ error: errorThrown }]);
            });
        }
        return false;
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

this.addErrors() is no longer equal to self.addErrors() in your example.

Also, as stated, you .push() into an array, you don't do whatever it is you are trying to do...

```
self.addErrors.push(whateverError);
```

Comment: I will look at this more carefully because just changing the references and using push doesn't fix it. Actually it's been pushed properly as far as I can see using the extension for seeing ko bindings in chrome developer tools with the references I'm using. Will update

Comment: I could only mark one as the answer, so I marked the first one and updated the other one